# BQ aquaris 4.5 freezing on start up screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, startup, phone, bq, aquaris

today i factory reset my phone, worked fine.. then something went wrong again so i factory reset again( highly regret this now!)

i was downloading the apps i needed, i was on whatsapp entering my mobile number to set it up finally, then my mobile crashed, i had to turn my mobile off. since then i have not been able to access my phone. i turn it on it goes to the BQ screen then stays there for all eternity. any solution to this?

i have removed battery for a few minutes, removed sd card, rubbed battery,

all failed.

and the only way i can turn the phone off is by removing the battery.

i did googling with the keywords "bq aquaris freezing" and these forums kept coming up so thought i would sign up and look for a solution here.

need help with this one.. thank you guys/girls.

Comment: So can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You cannot access the battery unless you break the bq telephone. And there is no whatsapp on the Ubuntu system. So... what exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Go for a hard reset.

You can find the Ubuntu firmware in the following link:
http://www.mibqyyo.com/descargas/categorias/aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition/

You can follow these steps to install Ubuntu in your device. Remember that this procedure will erase all personal data and downloaded content on the device.

You can follow this video tutorial which is a step by step procedure on how to perform a Hard Reset:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQ94y8XEfLw&feature=youtu.be

- Select the latest firmware available and the drivers and tools to download it.
- Unzip both archives downloaded and move the folders inside, to the root of the partition (c:) of your PC.
- Go to the folder "Drivers" which has been moved to the root of your PC, and open the file "Install" or "Install.bat". Your PC will warn you that the drivers are unsigned, please continue with the installation. Please, right click on it and select to install using the administrator mode.
- Go to the folder "MTK SP Flash Tool" and execute"Flash_tool" or "Flash_tool.exe".
- Click on "Scatter-Loading" and select the file "Android_scatter_emmc" (or similar name)  which is in the unzipped folder named "firmware" that you moved to the root, and press "Open".
- Please, be careful and select "Firmware upgrade" from the dropdown list. If you select any other option, it may affect the proper functioning of the device .
- Click on "Download".
- Swich off your smartphone and connect it to your PC. The procedure will start immediately.
- When the procedure has finished, a green circle with the "OK" word will appear in the screen. This means that the Hard Reset was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem phone just shows bq icon and doesnt boot. Left it all night and let the battery go flat.

Re charged from USB and it booted OK, will however get sorted via link and upgrade software if it occurs again.